# How to add Page border of SSRS Report page

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating SSRS Report. I Want to Set A Page Border to my report.
when i am setting page border it excludes the header  and footer.Please provide Solution for page Border.

Answer (score 0):

select the text box, go to Text box Properties -> Border -> Outline -> OK.

Comment: i have already tried that but if i have header and footer it excludes header and footer ....but i need complete page border not on text box

Comment: You can go to the header & footer panel & right click to add border over them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Be1ng_Kr1Sh comments:

For the header set BorderStyle to solid for top, left, right

For the body set BorderStyle to solid for left, right

For the footer set BorderStyle to solid for bottom, left, right

Comment: I have tried this method ....This is working fine for me .the only problem is here is Border Size ..How i can change border Size ..Please can u guide me...Thanks

Comment: There is a BorderWidth property, which affects border size